# Screen capture from within iframe (cross origin domain)

Tags: javascript, iframe, http-headers, cross-domain, screen-capture

I have a website which I fully control, in which I embed my other application via iframe - this application prompts the user for screen sharing. So the prompt comes from within the inner, embedded document.

The website and the iframe are on different origins. I only need to capture the contents of actual iframe (not the website in which it is embedded) **via the screen capture api**, but I cannot get it to work - I'm getting an `Error: NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'getDisplayMedia' on 'MediaDevices': Access to the feature "display-capture" is disallowed by permission policy.` If the code is hosted on the same origin it works, but that won't be the case in the actual application.

Website:

```html
<iframe
    allow="display-capture"
    src="link"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-modals allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin"
    allowFullScreen>
</iframe>
```

On the iframe end I expose the following response headers:

```js
res.header('Permissions-Policy', 'display-capture=*');
res.header('Feature-Policy', 'display-capture=*');
```

Same with the actual website.

Both of the apps are running on https.

I found some docs on MDN but I can't figure out on which side do I miss the permissions in order to get it work. I can add all necessary headers / prompts / permissions where necessary, I'm just stuck how exactly am I supposed to get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I posted in the question is actually enough - just keep in mind that all nested iframes (and especially the top level one) need the `allow="display-capture"` attribute, as well as proper headers on the **parent** window. The best resource to read up on this is probably https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/permissions-policy/